# How to solve error message when try to start jpa on spring-boot?

Tags: spring, jpa

I have spring+jpa+rest application on spring-boot(try to implement)

Application for spring-boot:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("package")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package.dao", entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf")
@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have rest - controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import package.myService;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @PostMapping("create")
    public void test1(){
    }

    @PostMapping("{id}")
    public void test2(@RequestBody Object object){
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public void test3(@PathVariable Long id){
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public MyEntity() {
    }

    public MyEntity(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Repository is:

MyEntityRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepositoryextends JpaRepository<myEntity, Long>{
    public void findNameById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

application context in resouces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="riskMetricService" class="ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.service.RiskMetricServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

If needs, I can add pom.xml

> I have error message when try to strat: APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController
>   required a bean named 'emf' that could not be found.
>
> Action:

Where need to locate file with dbconnection configs?
How to solve this error message?

Answer (score 1):

in your application you are referencing an entity manager bean called emf

> entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf"

You should define it. you can do it in your application context or in a 
@Configuration Class.

For example you could define it this way :

```
    <bean id="emf"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            ......
    </bean>
```